# All my Tool Options in GIMP are lost or unable to move

Tags: unity, gimp

I have constantly had this problem with GIMP detaching my Tool Options. I always look for a solution on the internet, and usually I find one. This time, I couldn't. My screen looks like this:

[image]

I want my Tool Options and Paintbrush tab back and attached to the LEFT side of my window.

Things I have already tried:

- Going under the "Windows" tab and adding them manually. They won't "click and drag" to the left. In fact, I can't even find my Paintbrush tab.
- Going under the "Windows" tab and clicking "Single-Window Mode."
- Clicking and dragging doesn't work regardless if the tab is attached or detached.
- Uninstalling GIMP completely and reinstalling it.

What is the problem here and how do I move them?

Comment: Thanks so much Terrance, that worked!! Ahhhh, I'm so happy now!

Comment: You're welcome! We will close this one as a duplicate of that question so others that come along with the same issue can go to that answer(s).  Just procedural is all.